# How can I make a "convolutional" kernel with 3x3 px input and 2x2 px output?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a toy problem trying to increase the resolution of an image by a factor of 2 with a keras model. A basic operation to achieve this with keras is Conv2DTranspose. Using the functional model API, I split each pixel into four with:

```
upconv = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=2, filters=3)(previous)
```

The resulting transpose convolution is a (1*1*3)*(2*2*3) = 36 parameter operation that gives me the output resolution I want.

What I would like to do is include the neighboring pixels from the input image in the convolution kernel. For each pixel on the input, I want to include every adjacent pixel, or 3x3 pixels; the output would be the same (2x2 pixels with stride 2). This kernel would have (3*3*3)*(2*2*3) = 324 parameters.

I haven't been able to find any information about how to do this. Any ideas?

For now I'm using a two-layer workaround:

1. A Conv2D layer with 3x3 kernel and stride 1 (and zero padding to conserve pixel count) with 9 filters;
2. I apply my Conv2DTranspose layer as before to the output.

This captures the desired information and the idea is that it encodes the location info along the filter dimension and the total parameter count is 351, so it should have enough degrees of freedom to approximate the same effect.

I may also try using 27 filters in the intermediate layer, which would be sort of like "flattening" the 3x3x3 pixel information into one "pixel". The only drawback is this leads to a total of 1,053 parameters; way more than before. The upside is it gives me an opportunity to introduce nonlinearity to this encoding step; maybe the model can benefit from these extra parameters.